# Return a variable from Php to JQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**What I'm Trying to Do**
I want to send a user's name and score to my php page where it inserts the data into the database, then spits out an html string showing the top ten scores.

**What's Actually Happening**
I enter the user's name and score and click submit.  The data is sent over to php which then stores it in the database.  The php file then constructs the string correctly which I can see by visiting the php page directly.  However, the string is not returned back to my JQuery.

```
$("#leaderboardForm > input[type=image]").click(function() {
    var theName = $("input#leaderboardName").val();
    var theScore = $("input#theScore").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../admin/submitleaderboard.php",
      data: { leaderboardName: theName, theScore: theScore },
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(leaderboard) {
        $("div#deadStats").html(leaderboard);
      },
      error: function() {
          alert("An error occured submitting your score.");
      }
    });
});
```

```
    $name = $_POST['leaderboardName'];
$score = $_POST['theScore'];

$sql="INSERT INTO leaderboard (leaderboard_date,leaderboard_name,leaderboard_score) VALUES (CURDATE(),'$name','$score')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$sql="SELECT * FROM leaderboard";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $leaderboard = $leaderboard . "<div style='width: 433px; padding: 8px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #300; margin-bottom: 5px;'>";
    $leaderboard = $leaderboard . "<div style='width: 200px; height: 30px; float: left;'>";
    $leaderboard = $leaderboard . "<span style='color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;'>" . $row['leaderboard_name'] . "</span></div>";
    $leaderboard = $leaderboard . "<div style='width: 200px; height: 30px; float: left;'>";
    $leaderboard = $leaderboard . "<span style='color: #A00; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;'>" . $row['leaderboard_score'] . "</span></div>";
    $leaderboard = $leaderboard . "</div>";
}
echo $leaderboard;
mysql_close();
```

Comment: in your `$.ajax`, `dataType: "json",` means you're going to return `json` data but your returned data doesn't seem like `json`

Answer (score 1):

Your `$.ajax` method expects `json` response. You're returning `text/plain`. change last php line into:

```
echo json_encode($leaderboard);
```

It will work like that but to be really correct, you should probably add:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

To the top of your PHP page before anything is outputted too.

#### Update

I see you're reading through database rows and echoing it in php. Then you want to append it onto your page.

The **easiest** way to do this is to just remove `dataType: "html"` part in your `$.ajax` call. (Don't do any of the things above **update** title, I assumed you were returning an array there).

Comment: I have made these updates to my code, tested it and still get the same result.

Comment: Read the update, don't do any of the stuff I told you above, do just what I said in **update** part.

Comment: Can't be. You must have a problem somewhere else then. Check if your `div#deadStats` is ok.

Add `alert(leaderboard)` to your `success` event to check if it is being called and if data is passed.

Comment: No luck with the alert box.  The only box that appears is the error alert.  I am still not receiving any response data though according to Firebug and developer tools.

Comment: So there is something wrong with your response. I see you use `POST` method, are you reading data sent by ajax using `$_REQUEST['variable_name']`? Check your file path too, is it "hitting" the file at all?

Comment: I have updated my original post to show my full php file.  I am still making no progress with this and it's baffling me.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are expecting html as an answer, yet you declare the datatype of your ajax request to json:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Try removing it, or setting it to html.

Comment: I was trying the html datatype before with no luck.

Comment: did you inspect the ajax response (network tab in chrome developer tools)? What is the actual response? And did you try removing dataType all together, ajax should try to determine it automaticllly if the property is left out.

Comment: The actual response reads "This request has no response data available."

Comment: then it will be on the php side... try to do a print_r of the $row array and see if you get at least something in your response now...

Comment: When I visit the php page directly, it prints the leaderboard string perfectly.

Comment: How can you visit it directly if you are fetching the variables trough a POST? There is no insert beeing executed I suppose? Perhaps that is where your php is failing...

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the solution.

For some reason, if I am using an input>image or input>submit as the trigger for my Ajax, I get the error.  If I use a div/span/textfield or any other element that does not typically submit a form, it works just fine.

Can anybody elaborate on this?